# What is "int" in this line?

Tags: java, arrays, types

I'm attempting to write an array inside a for loop that doesn't seem to make any sense with the error.

```
String[][] userName;

userName = new String[3][4];

for(int x=1; x<= 4; x++) {
    for(int y=-1; y <= 3; y++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student name for row "+x+"column "+y+" ==>");
        userName[x-1][y-1] = (String) System.in.read();
    }
}
```

For the line:

```
userName[x-1][y-1] = (String) System.in.read()
```

it gives an error:

```
Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
```

But what in that line is classified as `int`? The only ones I know are the `[x-1][y-1]`, but they're numbers to find the place in the array, also, I even deleted them, and it still says the same error.

What is classified as `int`, and how do I fix this error?

Comment: JavaScript isn't Java.

Comment: Oh... Okay. Did not know that. Sorry.

Comment: I... uh, I'm not sure which I'm learning then. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 for(int x=1; x<= 4; x++)
2 {
3  for(int y=-1; y <= 3; y++)
4  {
5   System.out.println("Enter student name for row "+x+"column "+y+" ==>");
6   userName[x-1][y-1] = (String) System.in.read();
7  }
8 }
```

Lets split this loop bit by bit.
On line 6, You are taking an Integer input through System.in.read() line, but your array is basically String datatype! So, you cast it to String. however, you cannot really insert int to a string without **Integer.toString(System.in.read())**. It's the normal way! However, the easiest way would be

```
userName[x-1][y-1] = "" + System.in.read();
```

Java reads a line from right to left. So it will take an input and append it to an empty String and then put it inside userName array!.

(Thanks to [Pavneet Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936904/pavneet-singh) for noticing me)
(Thanks to [Erwin Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981744/erwin-bolwidt) for correcting me out. I did not notice it was String!)

Or, you can use [Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

To do that you will need add the following codes.
add the following before your class line **(public class)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then when you class starts inside **public static void main(..)**, on the first line or in any convenient line before function, you will write the following line

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

It initializes the scanner. Then you can use the scanner class!

```
userName[x-1][y-1] = sc.next();
```

See through scanner class, you will need to specify the data type you will be providing! So, if you/user provides String or float or boolean value, it will throw an error and program will end/crash! Pretty effective, if you are trying to avoid wrong datatype.

Finally, you probably have an error in your loop declaration on line 3. 
You can run the loop from **y = -1** but, in Java, array indexes starts from 0. So, there is no index on **y - 1 = - 1 - 1 = -2**, it will throw an error! To avoid this all you have to do is, declare your loop from y = 1.

```
for(int y = 1, y <= 3; y++)
```

Happy programming! Cheers!

Comment: @Zar, Thanks. ^_^

Comment: you don't have to cast it  `(int) System.in.read()` it's already an int

Comment: Sorry. Did not notice!

Comment: `userName` is declared as `String[][] userName;` --> it's an array of an array of **String**s. Not **int**s as you say. You can't assign an int to an element of that array. That's why the OP was trying to cast it to String. You also cannot assign the result of `Scanner.nextInt()` to it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, sorry. fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for the info! ^.^ My apologies for making so much mistakes, heh. I was learning from a course that told me to type that down. Usually, it just makes minor mistakes like no semicolon or the loop error that you pointed out (I should have seen that). I was tired and gutsy to get today's bit of work done (Fridays and all, hehe). I'm also tired. >.> Still no excuse to make so many mistakes, but hey. But thanks again for the info! Once I get back to the lesson, I'll be sure to try out all your helpful answers and see if they work!

Comment: @L7vanmatre, thats okay dude. Glad to be helpful! and also thanks to many other people who helped me to modify my mistakes! We were all a beginner at some points, so no problem on making a few (or a lot!) of mistakes! Good luck (y)

Comment: Haha, yeah, that makes sense. Thanks mate!

Comment: Thanks again man! Since yours broke it down and elaborated more, I tried this one first! I had some issues, but it was when the program asks for more columns/rows then is in userName. X should have equalled 3 and Y should have equalled 4 in the loops. Fixed that, and the thing finally went successfully! It feels great... I think I'm gonna love coding! :D

Answer (score 2):

because `System.in.read()` will read bytes will return the value within range of 0-255 so you don't need it , you want to read String then either use `Scanner` or `Streams`

```
Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);

for(int x=1; x<= 4; x++) {
    for(int y=-1; y <= 3; y++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student name for row "+x+"column "+y+" ==>");
        userName[x-1][y-1] = scan.read();
    }
}
```

Scanner (import java.util.Scanner)

```
Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);

scan.read(); // read the next word
scan.readLine(); // read the whole line
```

or

Streams

```
InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);  
String str=br.readLine();
```

Scanner is easy , comes with lot of functionality [link to doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java) , Streams can be used to read bulk data which sometimes can't be read by scanner

Answer (score 0):

Before using `System.in.read()` you should have done some research on it. The `System.in.read()` method reads bytes of data from input stream and return the data as integer. So you can only use an integer or a character variable to store the data. String variables cannot store the data returned by the method `System.in.read()`. And this is the reason why you get the exception

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

And also use a try catch block when you are using `System.in.read()` method.